# Query that gets students with their courses in same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I need a query that will get students whom get Course1, Course2 and Course3. I can query it like that:

```
SELECT k.name as firstname, k.surname as lastname, k.Email
FROM Students k
JOIN StudentCourses dn ON dn.StudentID = k.StudentID
WHERE dn.CourseID IN
(SELECT CourseID FROM Courses WHERE CourseName IN ('Course1','Course2','Course3'))
```

But i need a result set like that: Name, Surname, Email, Course1, Course2, Course3. No multiple rows for a student, one row and write course name if students get that course.

In fact i can imagine how to write that query (with subselects), wonder about better alternatives.

Comment: Use PIVOT/UNPIVOT operator, you can pull the rows with just a student and course column and use the operator to transpose the data

Comment: or throw some sample data (no image) aand output desire

Comment: Assuming you have only 3 courses I have hard coded the case otherwise the query needs to be changed 
<code>
SELECT k.name as firstname, k.surname as lastname, k.Email,
Case when dn.CourseName ='Course1' then 'Course1' 
else '-' end AS Course1,

Case when dn.CourseName ='Course2' then 'Course2' 
else '-' end AS Course2,


Case when dn.CourseName ='Course3' then 'Course3' 
else '-' end AS Course3,

FROM Students k
JOIN StudentCourses dn ON dn.StudentID = k.StudentID
Join CourseId AS ci on dn.CourseId =  ci.id
</code>

Comment: What do you want to display under the coursename for each row?

Comment: I can wright course name or yes/no. Doesn't matter.

Comment: Sumant, StudentCourses has no courseName. It's in Courses..

Comment: Ah ok. Sumant, yours worked after that small change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `PIVOT` table operator to do this, something like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT 
    k.name as firstname, 
    k.surname as lastname, 
    k.Email, 
    c.CourseName, c.CourseID
  FROM Students k
  JOIN StudentCourses dn ON dn.StudentID = k.StudentID
  INNER JOIN Courses c ON dn.CourseID = c.CourseID
  WHERE c.CourseName IN  ('Course1','Course2','Course3')
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE AS c
PIVOT
(
  MAX(CourseID)
  FOR CourseName IN ([Course1], [Course2], [Course3])
) u;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44919/1)

---

**Note that,** Since you don't have other columns to display under each column of course for each students, this query will display `CourseID` value for each course name, `null` if the student doesn't have this course. You should choose to display more appropriate column instead, like mark for example:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT 
    k.name as firstname, 
    k.surname as lastname, 
    k.Email, 
    c.CourseName, dn.Mark
  FROM Students k
  JOIN StudentCourses dn ON dn.StudentID = k.StudentID
  INNER JOIN Courses c ON dn.CourseID = c.CourseID
  WHERE c.CourseName IN  ('Course1','Course2','Course3')
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE AS c
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Mark)
  FOR CourseName IN ([Course1], [Course2], [Course3])
) u;
```

- [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8d49/3)

This will give you:

```
| firstname | lastname | Email | Course1 | Course2 | Course3 |
|-----------|----------|-------|---------|---------|---------|
|  StudentA |     test |  test |      19 |      20 |      15 |
|  StudentB |     test |  test |      16 |      17 |      20 |
|  StudentC |     test |  test |      20 |      19 |      15 |
```

Also note that, you should be careful about the columns you choose in the anchor query:

```
...
SELECT 
    k.name as firstname, 
    k.surname as lastname, 
    k.Email, 
    c.CourseName, dn.Mark
...
```

Because the `PIVOT` table operator will group by all the columns except the columns you listed and used to pivot:

```
MAX(CourseID)
  FOR CourseName IN
```

So in your case, it will group by `firstname, lastname, Email`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a better query than yours and use `MAX(CASE ...)` to achieve your expected result like this:

```
SELECT k.name as firstname, k.surname as lastname, k.Email,
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.CourseName = 'Course1' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) As Course1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.CourseName = 'Course2' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) As Course2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.CourseName = 'Course3' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) As Course3
FROM Students k
JOIN StudentCourses dn ON dn.StudentID = k.StudentID
JOIN Courses c ON c.CourseID = dn.CourseID AND c.CourseName Like 'Course[1-3]'
GROUP BY k.name, k.surname, k.Email;
```